# React/TypesScript + Webpack Module Federation - Loading script failed. (error: https://local.mydomain.com:444/remoteEntry.js)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I'm having an issue when trying to get a microfrontend working inside another app. I've created a POC for this before albeit it was not using TypeScript or React 18 and it worked fine. I even mirrored the config.

The issue I'm having is when the container application comes to load a "component" from the remote app. Even when the remote app is not running, it's still providing the exact same error. This error is printed twice within the site/dev console.

## Error:

```
Loading script failed.
(error: https://local.mydomain.com:444/remoteEntry.js)
while loading "./loading" from webpack/container/reference/OtherApp
ScriptExternalLoadError: Loading script failed.
(error: https://local.mydomain.com:444/remoteEntry.js)
while loading "./loading" from webpack/container/reference/OtherApp
    at webpack/container/reference/OtherApp (https://local.mydomain.co.uk/main.js:159043:25)
    at __webpack_require__ (https://local.mydomain.co.uk/runtime.js:28:33)
    at initExternal (https://local.mydomain.co.uk/runtime.js:352:28)
    at __webpack_require__.I (https://local.mydomain.co.uk/runtime.js:411:15)
    at https://local.mydomain.co.uk/runtime.js:921:47
    at webpack/sharing/consume/default/jss/jss (https://local.mydomain.co.uk/runtime.js:975:76)
    at https://local.mydomain.co.uk/runtime.js:1120:56
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at __webpack_require__.f.consumes (https://local.mydomain.co.uk/runtime.js:1103:36)
    at https://local.mydomain.co.uk/runtime.js:146:40
```

To give some perspective of this. I have a container app running via https on the default SSL port. I then have my remote app running on HTTPS but on port 444.

The **webpack configurations** for both apps are;

## Container app:

```
import path from 'path';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin from 'fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin';
import ESLintPlugin from 'eslint-webpack-plugin';
import Webpack, { Configuration, ProvidePlugin } from 'webpack';
import Dotenv from 'dotenv-webpack';
import PackageDependencies from '../package.json';

interface Props {
  env: string;
}
export default ({ env }: Props): Configuration => {
  return {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/index.jsx'),
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../build'),
      publicPath: 'auto',
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/i,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: [
                '@babel/preset-env',
                '@babel/preset-react',
                '@babel/preset-typescript',
              ],
              envName: env,
            },
          },
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
          type: 'asset/resource',
        },
        {
          test: /\.m?js/,
          resolve: {
            fullySpecified: false,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.jsx'],
      modules: ['node_modules', path.resolve(__dirname, '../src')],
      fallback: {
        fs: false,
        tls: false,
        net: false,
        zlib: false,
        http: false,
        https: false,
        crypto: require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),
        stream: require.resolve('stream-browserify'),
        buffer: require.resolve('buffer'),
        path: require.resolve('path-browserify'),
        os: require.resolve('os-browserify/browser'),
      },
      alias: {
        process: 'process/browser',
        src: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
        components: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/components'),
        utils: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/utils'),
      },
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'public/index.html',
      }),
      new ProvidePlugin({
        React: 'react',
        process: 'process/browser',
        Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'],
      }),
      new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
        async: false,
      }),
      new ESLintPlugin({
        extensions: ['...', 'ts', 'js'],
      }),
      new Dotenv({
        path: `.env.${env}.local`,
        systemVars: true,
      }),
      new Webpack.container.ModuleFederationPlugin({
        name: 'ContainerApp',
        filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
        remotes: {
          OtherApp:
            'OtherApp@https://local.mydomain.com:444/remoteEntry.js',
        },
        shared: [
          {
            ...PackageDependencies.dependencies,
            dayjs: {
              singleton: true,
              eager: true,
              requiredVersion: PackageDependencies.dependencies.dayjs,
            },
            'launchdarkly-react-client-sdk': {
              singleton: true,
              eager: true,
              requiredVersion:
                PackageDependencies.dependencies[
                  'launchdarkly-react-client-sdk'
                ],
            },
            jss: {
              singleton: true,
              eager: true,
              requiredVersion: PackageDependencies.dependencies.jss,
            },
            'jss-rtl': {
              singleton: true,
              eager: true,
              requiredVersion: PackageDependencies.dependencies['jss-rtl'],
            },
            notistack: {
              singleton: true,
              eager: true,
              requiredVersion: PackageDependencies.dependencies.notistack,
            },
            clsx: {
              singleton: true,
              eager: true,
              requiredVersion: PackageDependencies.dependencies.clsx,
            },
            'prop-types': {
              singleton: true,
              eager: true,
              requiredVersion: PackageDependencies.dependencies['prop-types'],
            },
            '@mui/material': {
              singleton: true,
              eager: true,
              requiredVersion:
                PackageDependencies.dependencies['@mui/material'],
            },
            '@mui/system': {
              singleton: true,
              eager: true,
              requiredVersion: PackageDependencies.dependencies['@mui/system'],
            },
            '@mui/styled-engine': {
              singleton: true,
              eager: true,
              requiredVersion:
                PackageDependencies.dependencies['@mui/styled-engine'],
            },
            '@emotion/styled': {
              singleton: true,
              eager: true,
              requiredVersion:
                PackageDependencies.dependencies['@emotion/styled'],
            },
            '@emotion/react': {
              singleton: true,
              eager: true,
              requiredVersion:
                PackageDependencies.dependencies['@emotion/react'],
            },
            '@microsoft/applicationinsights-react-js': {
              singleton: true,
              eager: true,
              requiredVersion:
                PackageDependencies.dependencies[
                  '@microsoft/applicationinsights-react-js'
                ],
            },
            '@microsoft/applicationinsights-web': {
              singleton: true,
              eager: true,
              requiredVersion:
                PackageDependencies.dependencies[
                  '@microsoft/applicationinsights-web'
                ],
            },
            history: {
              singleton: true,
              eager: true,
              requiredVersion: PackageDependencies.dependencies.history,
            },
            axios: {
              singleton: true,
              eager: true,
              requiredVersion: PackageDependencies.dependencies.axios,
            },
            'react-helmet': {
              singleton: true,
              eager: true,
              requiredVersion: PackageDependencies.dependencies['react-helmet'],
            },
            'react-query': {
              singleton: true,
              eager: true,
              requiredVersion: PackageDependencies.dependencies['react-query'],
            },
            react: {
              singleton: true,
              eager: true,
              requiredVersion: PackageDependencies.dependencies.react,
            },
            'react-dom': {
              singleton: true,
              eager: true,
              requiredVersion: PackageDependencies.dependencies['react-dom'],
            },
            'react-router-dom': {
              singleton: true,
              eager: true,
              requiredVersion:
                PackageDependencies.dependencies['react-router-dom'],
            },
            'react-router': {
              singleton: true,
              eager: true,
              requiredVersion: PackageDependencies.dependencies['react-router'],
            },
          },
        ],
      }),
    ],
  };
};
```

## Other App:

```
import path from "path";
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from "html-webpack-plugin";
import ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin from "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin";
import ESLintPlugin from "eslint-webpack-plugin";
import Webpack, { Configuration, ProvidePlugin } from "webpack";
import PackageDependencies from "../package.json";

interface Props {
  env: string;
}
export default ({ env }: Props): Configuration => {
  return {
    entry: "./src/index.ts",
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../build"),
      publicPath: "auto",
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/i,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
              presets: [
                "@babel/preset-env",
                "@babel/preset-react",
                "@babel/preset-typescript",
              ],
              envName: env,
            },
          },
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
          type: "asset/resource",
        },
        {
          test: /\.m?js/,
          resolve: {
            fullySpecified: false,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js", ".jsx"],
      fallback: {
        fs: false,
        tls: false,
        net: false,
        path: false,
        zlib: false,
        http: false,
        https: false,
        stream: false,
        crypto: require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
      },
      alias: {
        process: "process/browser",
      },
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: "public/index.html",
      }),
      new ProvidePlugin({
        process: "process/browser",
      }),
      new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
        async: false,
      }),
      new ESLintPlugin({
        extensions: ["js", "jsx", "ts", "tsx"],
      }),
      new Webpack.container.ModuleFederationPlugin({
        name: "OtherApp",
        filename: "remoteEntry.js",
        exposes: {
          "./loading": "./src/components/loading",
        },
        shared: [
          {
            ...PackageDependencies.dependencies,
            react: {
              singleton: true,
              eager: true,
              requiredVersion: PackageDependencies.dependencies.react,
            },
            "react-dom": {
              singleton: true,
              eager: true,
              requiredVersion: PackageDependencies.dependencies["react-dom"],
            },
            "axios-retry": {
              singleton: true,
              eager: true,
              requiredVersion: PackageDependencies.dependencies["axios-retry"],
              version: PackageDependencies.dependencies["axios-retry"],
            },
          },
        ],
      }),
    ],
  };
};
```

## Things I've tried:

- Added `optimization: { splitChunks: { chunks: "async", }, }` to the remote app
- Added `publicPath: 'auto'` to both webpack configs
- In the network tab, when the remote app is running, I can see it has a status code of 200 for retrieving the remoteEntry.js file from the 'OtherApp'

## Versions (both apps):

- "webpack": "^5.88.2",
- "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
- "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1",

At this point I'm out of ideas. Can anyone spot anything wrong here or have any other possible solutions please?

Thanks.